# Regex optional grouping match

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I am trying to get all quoted strings in the below string:

```
a.a("Camera2", "onPictureTaken # ENTER..");
a.a("Camera2", "Save path :" + this.a.c + " is SAVED");
Camera c = Camera.open();
```

Regex:

```
a.*\"((?:\"|.)*?)\"
```

My problem is it's returning " is SAVED" as Match 2 Group 1.

Ideally it should have two matches for Match 2.

Group 1. "Save path :"
Group 2. " is SAVED"

https://regex101.com/r/iEgndD/2/

How can I fix this regex to return two matches for Match 2. Please help.

Comment: Why not use a well-known string literal regex like https://regex101.com/r/oYNTmV/1?

Comment: This is used to find code with a.a("ignore", "this string" + dontneed+ "this string") types of strings in java files

Comment: Parsing code with a single regex is not recommended, it will be long and unwieldly. Look, I have tried a bit, and got [`(?<!\S)([a-zA-Z$_][\w$]*\.)*a(?:\.[a-zA-Z$_][\w$]*)*(?:\W*\"([^\"]*)\")+`](https://regex101.com/r/QoqgxN/1). It looks as if it extracts the required substrings, but it will surely break with other strings once.